# Navegar despues de iniciar sesión

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Estoy realizando una app en Swift y SwiftUI la cual se conecta a un webservice y va haciendo peticiones https. Pude conectarme con el login y hacer la petición correctamente, pero cuando quiero que cambie de view no lo hace. La idea es que al entrar la app este el inicio de sesión con un boton para mantener la sesión iniciada. Al usuario lo estoy guardando con UserDefaults. El webservice devuelve un json con id, nick, grupo, persona y hashActual, luego se pueden hacer peticiones solo con el nick y el hashActual.

Tengo los siguientes codigos:

LoginViewViewModel:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class APIFetchHandler: ObservableObject {
    @Published var legajo = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    @Published var errorMessage = ""
    
    static let sharedInstance = APIFetchHandler()
    
    func postAPIData() {
        
        guard self.validate() else {
            return
        }
        
        let url = "https://'url'/login";
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "nick": legajo,
            "password": password
        ]
        AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseData { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    // GUARDA EL ESTUDIANTE EN UserDefaults
                    let student = try JSONDecoder().decode(Student.self, from: data)
                    if let encodedStudent = try? JSONEncoder().encode(student) {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedStudent, forKey: "student")
                        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                        print("Student saved to UserDefaults")
                        self.errorMessage = ""
                    } else {
                        print("Error encoding student object")
                    }
                    
                    // PRINTEAR UserDefaults PARA VER SI SE GUARDO CORRECTAMENTE
                    if let savedStudentData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "student") {
                        if let savedStudent = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Student.self, from: savedStudentData) {
                            print(savedStudent)
                        } else {
                            print("Error decoding student object")
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("No student data found in UserDefaults")
                    }
                } catch {
                    if let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode, statusCode == 401 {
                        print("Credenciales incorrectas.")
                        self.errorMessage = "Legajo/Contraseña incorrectos."
                    }
                    return
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("------------ ERROR ------------")
                print(error)
                print("------------ ERROR ------------")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func validate() -> Bool {
        guard !legajo.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty,
              !password.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
            self.errorMessage = "Llenar todos los campos, por favor."
            return false
        }
    
        return true
    }
}
```

MainViewViewModel:

```
import Foundation

class MainViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var savedStudent: Student?
    
    init() {
        loadSavedStudent()
    }
    
    func loadSavedStudent() {
        if let savedStudentData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "student") {
            if let savedStudent = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Student.self, from: savedStudentData) {
                self.savedStudent = savedStudent
            } else {
                print("Error al decodificar el estudiante.")
            }
        } else {
            print("No existe ningun estudiante logueado.")
        }
    }
}
```

MainView:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = MainViewViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        if viewModel.savedStudent != nil {
            HomeView()
        } else {
            LoginView()
        }
    }
}
```

LoginView:

```
struct LoginView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = APIFetchHandler()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("UTN - FRVM")
                .font(.title)
            
            Text("Iniciar sesión")
            
            Form {
                if !viewModel.errorMessage.isEmpty {
                    Text(viewModel.errorMessage)
                        .foregroundStyle(.red)
                }
                
                TextField("Legajo", text: $viewModel.legajo)
                    .textFieldStyle(DefaultTextFieldStyle())
                
                SecureField("Password", text: $viewModel.password)
                    .textFieldStyle(DefaultTextFieldStyle())
            
                Button {
                    viewModel.postAPIData()
                } label: {
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        
                        Text("Iniciar sesión")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .bold()
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qué código tiene el login view?

Comment: @Bicho ahi lo agregue!